# Plotlib superior labels not changing

Tags: python, plotly

I got the graph as you see and with this code but I want to change the format of the label from year=2034 to only the year number, tho I have no idea and im trying without any success.

The code:

```
fig = px.bar(fin_df, x='month', y=['vol_prod', 'vol_cons'], barmode='group', facet_col='year',
             color_discrete_map=colors)

fig.update_xaxes(title_text=None, ticktext=[str(year) for year in fin_df['year'].unique()], tickmode='array', tickvals=fin_df['year'].unique())
fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=False, row=1, col=1)

fig.update_layout(
    yaxis_title="Values",
)

fig.update_layout(autosize=True, width=1000, height=500, dragmode=False)
```

The image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azTuv.png)

I was expecting to reformat the upper label.

Comment: The title of the subplot in this case is included in the string annotation of the layout, which can be done by forcing a change in the last listing.　`print(fig.layout);` `fig.layout.annotations[-1]['text'] = '2034'`